# Java 8 expression evaluation sequence

Tags: java, java-8

I have a case like

```
MyClass.invoke( anObject.setSystem() );
```

Is there a guarantee that `anObject.setSystem()` will be called before MyClass is loaded? As the initialization code of MyClass depends on the result of `anObject.setSystem()`.

It is running with Java 8. Any suggestions/hints would be appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: so invoke is a static method?

Comment: what you mean by "loaded"?

Comment: its very dangerous approach, as somebody could use some other method from MyClass before, so it will be loaded

Comment: Whether or not there is a guarantee, I would not have your code have such a fragile, invisible dependency. It is best to make such a dependency explicit.

Comment: invoke is a static method. Loaded means the static init part of MyClass is executed. The reason of doing so is I need some init done at runtime, and it has to take place after anObject.setSystem(). And I only want those initialization done once.

Comment: then why don't you just move everything from the static init part to the invoke method?

Comment: How can the initialization code of `MyClass` depend on the result of `anObject.setSystem()`? How does the initialization code of `MyClass` learn about that result?

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass` will be loaded and all of its static fields and static initializers will be initialized before `MyClass.invoke()` is called.

See [JLS 12.14.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> T is a class and an instance of T is created.
>
> T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.               <------------ right here
>
> A static field declared by T is assigned.
>
> A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
>
> T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @Holger and @gigi's comments, there was still the question as to whether the invocation that triggers the loading of the class occurs before or after the evaluation of the argument expression passed into it.  I think the answer to that is in [JLS 15.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4), which states,

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. Second, the argument expressions are evaluated. Third, the accessibility of the method to be invoked is checked. Fourth, the actual code for the method to be executed is located. Fifth, a new activation frame is created, synchronization is performed if necessary, and control is transferred to the method code.

The evaluation of argument expressions (step 2) occurs before the code to execute the method is located, (step 4, which probably results in the class being loaded and statically initialized) and only then, in the final step, is the static method invoked.

Comment: The question was not whether `MyClass` is loaded before `MyClass.invoke()` is invoked (I guess, that’s understood), but whether `MyClass` will be loaded after `anObject.setSystem()` has been invoked.

Comment: Precisely, Holger. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: From what I've tried, MyClass is loaded after anObject.setSystem() is executed

Comment: Good point.  I had assumed that since the evaluation of anObject.setSystem() only occurs at the behest of the evaluation of MyClass.invoke, and that MyClass.invoke would only be evaluated after MyClass was initialized, that, in a transitive manner, MyClass would be initialized before the evaluation that triggers the evaluation anObject.setSystem(). So, is the question does the beginning of the evaluation of MyClass.invoke cause MyClass to be initialized, or does the  call to invoke() after the anObject.setSystem() is called cause MyClass to be initialized?

Comment: I think you are right. The invocation of invoke method of MyClass triggers its loading